# How to read a three-digit year number meaning a decade?

Tags: dates

I came across this phrase,

> Plato’s Academy, founded in the **380s**, was the ultimate ancestor of the modern university (hence the English term academic).
>
> ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Plato))

Could you tell me how to read "380s"?

Comment: What year is it? 1380s?

Comment: It was in the 4th century AD. Sometime between 380 and 389.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are not interpreting it as Dan says? Maybe it's something too modern for a 4th century founding?  What institution is being described?   If so, a longer quote would help.  It could be a typo   for '30s  or '80s .

Comment: Do you mean how would that be spoken out loud? That’s a good question! My guess would be “three eighties” but I don’t think that I’ve ever heard something like that before.

Comment: thanks. 

the original phrase reads 

"Plato’s Academy, founded in the 380s, was the ultimate ancestor of the modern university (hence the English term academic)"  [https://www.britannica.com/biography/Plato]

and I was wondering how I should read it out loud.

Comment: I would speak “the three eighties” because I am accustomed to usage such as “the nineteen thirties”.

Comment: I'd certainly suppose "the three eighties", but it's not likely to come up a lot, and so it doesn't matter if you say "three hundred and eighties" instead. Most people don't talk about decades between 1000 BCE and 1000 CE very often: at the time they didn't use that sort of date, and wouldn't have used modern English anyway.

Comment: @DanBron No, not AD; it was BC.

Answer (score 1):

There's no special rule for three-digit years. Just as the 1980s are "the nineteen eighties," the 980s are "the nine eighties."

Comment: Yes, and these ones ran the opposite direction: the three-eighties ran from three eighty-nine up to three eighty. One year later it was three seventy-nine.